# Proof of convergence for a sequence composed by another sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that

$ y_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_n}{n}$

is convergent, knowing the fact that also $x_n$ is convergent?

Thanks

Comment: Squeeze it.${}$

Answer (score 1):

Surely you know the following fact:

> If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent sequences, then $a_n b_n, a_n+b_n$ also converge and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n b_n = (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n ) (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n)$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n+b_n = (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n )+(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n)$.

Since you know that $1/n$ and $x_n$ are convergent, this implies that $y_n$ is also convergent (and in fact $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n=0$).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking to prove that the running average is convergent. For that, first choose $N$ so that $|x - x_n| < \epsilon/2$ when $x > N$ for given $\epsilon > 0$. Then choose $M$ large enough so that $\sum_{n=1}^N |x_n| / M < \epsilon/2$. Then you will get that your average $y_n$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x$ when $n > M$..